# Node retrieving old TLS certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl

I used the following code to get the server TLS certificate for `stackoverflow.com`:

```
const tls = require('tls');

const conn = tls.connect({
  host: 'stackoverflow.com',
  port: 443,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
}, () => {
  const cert = conn.getPeerCertificate(false);
  console.log(cert);
  conn.destroy();
});
```

The result includes the following:

- subject: `{ CN: '*.stackexchange.com' }`
- issuer: `{ C: 'US', O: "Let's Encrypt", CN: 'R3' }`
- valid_from: `Dec  3 14:00:52 2020 GMT`
- valid_to: `Mar  3 14:00:52 2021 GMT`
- fingerprint256: `C6:D3:6E:68:38:EC...`

Note that it is an expired certificate.

By contrast, when I visit `stackoverflow.com` in Firefox, it loads a certificate with the following details:

- Not before: `Sun, 06 Mar 2022 14:17:27 GMT`
- Not after: `Sat, 04 Jun 2022 14:17:26 GMT`
- SHA-256: `04:F7:14:2A:28:EF:1F...`

It appears Node is obtaining an old certificate. Perhaps it is cached somewhere?

My platform is:

- Node v17.8.0
- Linux, x64, Manjaro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same invalid certificate with your original code, so I  took a look at the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tlsconnectoptions-callback), and it has the following interesting tidbit:

> Unlike the `https` API, `tls.connect()` does not enable the SNI
> (Server Name Indication) extension by default, which may cause some
> servers to return an incorrect certificate or reject the connection
> altogether. To enable SNI, set the `servername` option in addition to
> host.

Adding the `servername` option:

```
const tls = require('tls');

const conn = tls.connect({
  host: 'stackoverflow.com',
  servername: 'stackoverflow.com',
  port: 443,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
}, () => {
  const cert = conn.getPeerCertificate(false);
  console.log(cert);
  conn.destroy();
});
```

I obtain a valid certificate:

```
subject: [Object: null prototype] { CN: '*.stackexchange.com' },
[...]
valid_from: 'Mar  6 14:17:27 2022 GMT',
valid_to: 'Jun  4 14:17:26 2022 GMT',
[...]
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to be exactly it. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. Learned something new today :)